# No valign="middle" in Outlook 2010 after loading images

Tags: html, outlook, mailchimp, newsletter

there is an table with 4 cols. The first col have following values rowspan="2" and valign="middle". It works everywhere fine but not in Outlook 2010.

Before loading the images. The col is middle. But when I click on the Button 'Load Images' the col is top. (like you can see in the screenshots)

[image: Table before loading images]
[image: Table after loading images]

Comment: And if you change Outlook's settings so that it loads external images automatically?

Comment: Then it is top align at the beginning.